# download html using Curl Lib in korean language

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, libcurl, decoding

I am using `Curl LIB` to download html of a Korean website but the issue is i do not see the website characters properly an example is listed below :

Example i want to get price which is :

```
42,000원
```

But when i get the HTML i get it as :

```
42,000��
```

Same with all the other Korean characters what to do ? I encountered something similar in the past but that was in `HTTPWEBREQUEST` but have no idea how to deal with this now.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is a sample link [KOREAN SAMPLE SITE](http://www.secretlabel.co.kr/) . And the function i use is below (Curl Lib):

```
 public string Post(string URL, string post,string refferer)
    {
        result = "";
        try
        {
            string UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0";
            Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
            Easy easy = new Easy();
            Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, URL);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_REFERER, refferer);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, "6000000");
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERAGENT, UserAgent);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CookieFile);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CookieFile);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_ENCODING,Encoding.UTF8); // NOT SURE OF THIS

            if (post != "")
            {
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, true);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post);
            }


            if (URL.Contains("https"))
            {
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
                easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            }

            easy.Perform();
            easy.Cleanup();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

What do i need to add the get the return html as :

```
..meta name="description" content="시크릿라벨 ♩">
..meta name="keywords" content="시크릿라벨">
```

instead of `�` everywhere.

Comment: Where are you viewing the result? Can it handle unicode?

Comment: @ayuelkenbeck i have added this line to the post function lets see:
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_ENCODING,UTF8Encoding.Unicode);

Comment: @ayuelkenbeck no use, the issue is i dont know where to change the script to keep it good when downloading it using curlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue for me:

```
 result += Encoding.GetEncoding(949).GetString(buf);
```